# Second carousel slider category changed onclick using js not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm making a carousel slider using bootstrap that can be changed according to category selected. For example, if I click on hammer category the carousel will only display hammer image, and when i clicked on compass category, the carousel will only display compass image.

Everything went fine on the default or first carousel category (hammer), and the js event also went fine on change the category at click event, but after the category changed to compass, the carousel can't slide to the next image

Here is my html :

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column col-lg-7 alignment-items-stretch justify-content-center">
                        <div class="p-5">
                            <h2 data-aos="fade-right">Have a Look at Our Collections!</h2>
                            <p data-aos="fade-right">Brought to you from the most fresh and fashionable local brand all around Indonesia</p>
                            <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselex" data-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="carousel-inner" id="hammer">
                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/hammer.jpg" alt="geological hammer" data-aos="fade-up" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/hammer1.jpg" alt="" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/hammer2.jpg" alt="" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/hammer3.jpg" alt="" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/hammer4.jpg" alt="" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-inner d-none" id="compass">
                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/compass1.jpg" alt="geological hammer" data-aos="fade-up" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/compass2.webp" alt="" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="assets/img/image/compass3.webp" alt="" style="height:500px">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselex" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                  </a>
                                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselex" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                  </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-around alignment-items-stretch col-lg-5 itemgallery">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" data-aos="fade-left" onclick="hammerFunc()">HAMMER</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" data-aos="fade-right" onclick="compassFunc()">GEOLOGICAL COMPASS</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and here is my js :

```
function compassFunc() {
  var com = document.getElementById("compass");
    com.classList.remove("d-none");
  var ham = document.getElementById("hammer");
    ham.classList.add("d-none");
}

function hammerFunc() {
  var ham = document.getElementById("hammer");
    ham.classList.remove("d-none");
  var com = document.getElementById("compass");
    com.classList.add("d-none");
}
```

Comment: Instead of one carousel, you can have multiple carousels and show/hide carousel on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make 2 carousel slide each with crousel inner, carousel itm and carousel control, and make one of them d-none. So right now you hide the carousel itself